# React not rendering list after the state is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am creating a simple tracker which records all the activities done. It is my first project in react. I have created three state one for storing all the items(name of state is list), one for pending items(name of state is pending) , one for completed items(name of state is completed). The items have a button which when clicked marks it into done state and vice-versa. It is completely rendering items for main list. But for other two its not rendering. When I am checking with react developer tools, it is working fine, i.e. it is adding to pending list or completed list as it should. But it is not compiling them on screen. list is already filled with items. I have added all the code for just in case.

```
function Filters(props){
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState([]);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState([]);
  const [state, setState] = useState("None");
  const [list,setList] = useState([]);

  function viewState(){
    setState("View-all");
  }

   //it is getting the clicked item id and marking it complete in main list
  function markComplete(id){
    list.map((items,index)=>{
      if(index===id){
        if(items.done===true)
          items.done = false;
        else{
          items.done=true;
        }
      }
    })
  }

//i am simply scanning the main list and the items which are pending will be added to this list. //this happens whenever the person click on pending button
 function pendingState(){
    setState("pending-all");
    setPending([]);
    list.map(items=>{
      if(items.done!==true){
        setPending(prev=>{
          return [...prev,items];
        })
      }
    })
  }

  function completedState(){
    setState("completed-all");
    setCompleted([]);
    list.map(items=>{
      if(items.done===true){
        setCompleted(prev=>{
          return [...prev,items];
        })
      }
    })
  }

 return (
    <div>
      <div className="input-section">
        <Note setList={setList} />
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={viewState} >View All</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={completedState}>Completed</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={pendingState}>Pending</button>
      <div>
        {
          (()=>{
            if(state==="View-all")
            {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h1>Working {completed}</h1>
                  {(list).map((items,index)=>
                    {
                    return (

                      <Excercise
                        key={index}
                        id={index}
                        title={items.name}
                        list={props.list}
                        setList={props.setList}
                        content={items.desp}
                        markComplete={markComplete}
                        />
                    )
                  })}
                </div>
              )
            }
            else if(state==="completed-all")
            {
              return (
                <div>
                {completed.map((items,index)=>{
                  <Excercise
                    key={index}
                    id={index}
                    title={items.name}
                    list={props.list}
                    setList={props.setList}
                    content={items.desp}
                    markComplete={markComplete}
                    />
                })}
                </div>
              )
            }
  })()
        }

      </div>


    </div>);
}
```

Kindly help. Thank you.

Hi @DREW
The function code :

```
  function markComplete(id){
    setList(lists=>{
      lists.map(item=>{
      return item.id===id ?{...item,done: !item.done} : (item);})
      }
      )
  }
```

When I am using it instead of

```
 const markComplete = (id) => {
    setList((list) =>
      list.map((item) =>
        item.id === id
          ? {
              ...item,
              done: !item.done
            }
          : item
      )
    );
  };
```

it is showing, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"
arent the both same. If not, what am I doing wrong. Sorry for bugging so many times, I have just started with react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated things a bit. You only need one array to store the exercises in, the "pending" and "completed" states are easily derived from the `list` state and the `state` filter state value.

## Issues

- `markComplete` callback is mutating the `list` state. When updating the `list` state not only is a new array reference necessary, but also new element object references are necessary for the elements that are being updated.
- Uses poor boolean comparisons to set a boolean value. You can either toggle a boolean or set the value to the result of a boolean expression.
- Use the `viewState`, `pendingState`, and `completedState` handlers to simply set the filter value, and then derive the computed state when rendering by adding an inline `filter` function.
- Use the exercise `id` property as a React key *and* as the property used for toggling the completed (`done`) state.

## Solution

```
function Filters(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState("None");
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    ...
  ]);

  function viewState() {
    setState("View-all");
  }

  function pendingState() {
    setState("pending-all");
  }

  function completedState() {
    setState("completed-all");
  }

  const markComplete = (id) => {
    setList((list) =>
      list.map((item) =>
        item.id === id
          ? {
              ...item,
              done: !item.done
            }
          : item
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="input-section">
        <Note setList={setList} />
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={viewState}>
        View All
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={completedState}>
        Completed
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={pendingState}>
        Pending
      </button>
      <div>
        {list
          .filter((item) => {
            if (state === "pending-all") {
              return !item.done;
            } else if (state === "completed-all") {
              return item.done;
            }
            return true;
          })
          .map((item) => (
            <Excercise
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              done={item.done}
              title={item.name}
              content={item.desp}
              markComplete={markComplete}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-not-rendering-list-after-the-state-is-changed]

Comment: Hi Drew, will take care of mentioned errors next time, tysm for this. Just a small question, if in future If some part needs re-render, how can I achieve it. Some people have suggested useEffect but I am failing to understand where should I use it. Can you please share something on this. If I have to rerender, should I use in return section ?. ty,

Comment: @Shekharlohach I think those suggesting to use the `useEffect` are misinformed. The `useEffect` hook is used to issue a side-effect in response to a dependency updating, not to trigger a rerender. React will handle rerendering the component when one of the following occurs: (1) state is updated, (2) props are updated, (3) parent component rerenders. Just update the parts of state that the UI is derived from and React will rerender.

Comment: @Shekharlohach I think the other answers here suggesting to use the `useEffect` hook assumed that you might've needed to run some additional logic to update more state to trigger a rerender. It's not clear to me why they suggested that though since the callbacks (*except `markComplete` which was only mutating state*) all updated state and would trigger a rerender. Denis's answer was the only one that *actually* tried answering your question/addressing an issue.

Comment: Hi @Drew, sorry to bug again. Your method works perfectly, but I wanted to see why mine was not working so I can avoid this next time. I removed mutation. I kept the

Comment: @Shekharlohach The state mutation was the issue, but also IMHO it basically had too many moving parts. You had the `list` state of all the exercises and the filter value, and then two extra state arrays that you had to synchronize based on the first two states.

Comment: Hi drew, your code is very neat, so I having one more doubt. Sorry for questions, I have just started. You used const for markComplete. When I am using it as a function, it is showing errors like :"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')". I have added my function at bottom of post. Can you please tell why there is problem when I am using it as a function.

Comment: @Shekharlohach In your "function" version you used an arrow function with a body, i.e. `(list) => { ... }` but you forgot, or neglected, to return the result of `lists.map(.....)`. Arrow functions without a body scope implicitly return the result of `lists.map(....)`.

Comment: Regarding the use of a javascript `function` or using an arrow function, that mostly comes down to personal preference, or established coding standards/style guides if you work with a team.

Answer (score 0):

try to add dependecies in `useEffect`

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion, did you find any problem in what I wrote.  is there any reason why one list is being rendered completely fine and others two and not being rendered even tho their react developer shows data is present in those list after clicking on them ? ty

Answer (score 0):

in this function you are mutating a state, so in order to do so you need to use the setState function, in this case, it will be setList().

```
 function markComplete(id){
    list.map((items,index)=>{
      if(index===id){
        if(items.done===true)
          items.done = false;
        else{
          items.done=true;
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

So a better way to implement this function could be, and remember, everything time you need to update a state you don't want to change the state directly, instead, you should make a copy and set the state to that copy

```
function markComplete(id){
  const newList = [...list];

  newList.map((items,index)=>{
      if(index===id){
        if(items.done===true)
          items.done = false;
        else{
          items.done=true;
        }
      }
  }
  setList(newList)
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, your proposed solution is still mutating the state. The array is a new array but since arrays shallow copy by reference each `items` object still refers to the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

**The reason of your app not updating is because when your state changes react is not re-rendering it again.**

**so use `useEffect`, *there are many hooks which can be used as per requirement*.**

**try putting this line of code**

```
useEffect( ( ) => {
  
   console.log( 'Check console' );

}, [ dependency_here ] );
```

in `dependency_here` try adding `state`, `completed`, `pending` one by one and see the result.
You can also add multiple dependencies like `[ state, pending, etc.. ]`;

Try on your own you'll understand it faster.

Hope hint will help you!

Comment: Hey Prabhat, could you please share how and where can I use it ? if re-rendering is being done should I apply this in return where div is being returned ? ty.

Comment: useEffect is lifecycle method so this will never come inside the return. Use it on top after initializing your useState variables. better explained here `https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp`